# In search of a poem I once knew in German

Tags: poetry

Some years ago I memorizedand recited a poem in German.  I can only remember the last line, and several online searches were unsuccessful.   Does anyone recognize this?  The last line was

> Ich lache mit, und sterbe.

It is probably a short poem, and a well-known one.  I was in high school.

Comment: Google leads me to this: https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/pommeren/Gedichte/BdL/Heimk-63.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a poem of Heinrich Heine:

> Gedichte. Buch der Lieder. Die Heimkehr, 63.

> **Wer zum ersten Male liebt**

> Wer zum ersten Male liebt,
> Sei's auch glücklos, ist ein Gott;
> Aber wer zum zweiten Male
> Glücklos liebt, der ist ein Narr.

> Ich, ein solcher Narr, ich liebe
> Wieder ohne Gegenliebe!
> Sonne, Mond und Sterne lachen,
> Und ich lache mit – und sterbe.

See also [here](https://ia600302.us.archive.org/29/items/buchderliederneb00heinuoft/buchderliederneb00heinuoft.pdf) p.120 and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281792831_und_ich_lache_mit_-_und_sterbe_eine_lyrische_Hommage_a_Harry_Heine_1797_-_1856).

Comment: Apologies for accepting an answer so quickly, but this is exactly the poem.  Danke!

Comment: @nuggethead: there is no "more correct" answer than the correct one, so you were correct to accept.